# How can I make the Sub run is recalculated as a date is entered in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I make the Sub run is recalculated as a date is entered in a cell?

My goal is to run the macro when the date in cell B9 or C9 is updated.

```
Sub AgeReductionAge_Calc()
    Dim dt1 As Date
    Dim dt2 As Date
    Dim nWeeks As Integer

    dt1 = Range("B9")
    dt2 = Range("C9")

    nWeeks = DateDiff("yyyy", dt1, dt2)
    Range("D9") = nWeeks
End Sub

Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address = "$B$9" Then
    Call AgeReductionAge_Calc  
  End If
End Sub

Sub Worksheet_Change2(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address = "$C$9" Then
    Call AgeReductionAge_Calc
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it not work?  Did you place the macro in a worksheet module? Also, AFAIK your second one `..._Change2` won't fire on a worksheet change. You should add that part to the first `_Change` event's `If` statement.  `If Target.Address = "$B$9" Then ... ElseIf Target.Address = "$C$9" Then ...`

Comment: Why not just use the formula `=DATEDIF(B9,C9,"y")` in D9? See: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEDIF-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c

Comment: The worksheet was configured like that originally but several formulas are being transferred into VBA.